# Как добавить что-то новое на 2d спрайт в Unity, не рисуя его заново?

Tags: c#, 2d, unity3d, спрайт

Допустим, у меня есть спрайт героя. У него есть в руках меч. Но, к примеру, мечей в игре много, и они отличаются. Можно ли как-то прикрепить персонажу другой меч, который отличается цветом и чуть побольше, при этом не рисуя новый спрайт героя (спрайт другого меча есть отдельно), это всё нужно сделать в Unity (движке самой игры). Ведь если для каждого нового оружия рисовать измененный спрайт героя, то вариантов будут десятки, ведь ещё нужно нарисовать сторону, в которую он повернут и его анимацию. Есть идеи?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Полагаю стоит разделить спрайты персонажа по виду удерждания оружия. Допустил для коротких и двуручных мечей. Затем при анимировании перса создать точки для удержания оружия и цеплять префаб оружия к позиции и углу этой точки как дочерний объект скажем. И всё. При необходимости сменить оружие просто менять префаб

Comment: спасибо за ответ, учту!